# Is Yugabyte database type is supported in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Is Spring Batch JobRepository supporting the Yugabyte database?

We are planning to migrate to Yugabyte database type.   I was going through some of the Factory methods Like

```
DataFieldMaxValueIncrementer getIncrementer
```

It has list of Database type and in that no such Yugabyte databasetype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Yugabyte is not an officially supported database in Spring Batch. But according to Yugabyte's [website](https://www.yugabyte.com), it is Postgres compatible. So you might be bale to use the PostgreSQL DDL [provided](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-postgresql.sql) by Spring Batch and use it with Yugabyte.

Here is the section from the reference documentation on how to do that: [Non-standard Database Types in a Repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#nonStandardDatabaseTypesInRepository).